# How do I use the Instagram Graph API to schedule posts in the future?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, facebook-apps, instagram-graph-api

I have scoured [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing) and there is nothing that directly references a way to schedule instagram posts from the Graph API. With the Facebook API you can schedule a post by passing the `scheduled_publish_time` param, but the instagram API doesn't appear to have that option anywhere.

There are news posts from facebook saying "Instagram graph API now allows scheduled posts". Does this mean there is an actual facility in the graph API to schedule posts? Or is it just that instagram will allow you to implement your own automated scheduling logic and they won't get upset (because they used to)?

Looking for any information on how to schedule instagram image posts! (Hoping to avoid writing my own monolith)

Comment: Can you give an example of what news articles you are referring to there? I can only find stuff that is three and a half years old, https://www.facebook.com/business/news/instagram/instagram-api-features-updates, and there is says, "To get started with scheduling posts, please work with one of our Facebook Marketing Partners or Instagram Partners." And that does not sound like they were talking about any publicly available API to begin with, but one that is limited to partners.

Comment: this one is from January this year https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/01/26/introducing-instagram-content-publishing-api/

Comment: I can't find anything in the docs, neither in the media creation nor the publish part. I guess you have already tried what it says, when you try to use `scheduled_publish_time` like you would with normal Graph API? Guess you'd have to ask Facebook then, what they meant in that blog post.